# Get only the total with JFrog AQL

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli, artifactory-query-lang

I have this code for searching with frog AQL api:

```
   items.find({"name":{"$match":"abab-2.0.3.json"}})
```

its come back as response

`{
  "results": [
    {
      "repo": "npm-remote-cache",
      "path": ".npm/abab",
      "name": "abab-2.0.3.json",
      "type": "file",
      "size": 1124,
      "created": "2020-05-07T21:58:12.633Z",
      "created_by": "_system_",
      "modified": "2020-05-07T21:58:12.604Z",
      "modified_by": "_system_",
      "updated": "2020-05-07T21:58:12.633Z"
    }
  ],
  "range": {
    "start_pos": 0,
    "end_pos": 1,
    "total": 1
  }
}`

But I need only the "total" field.
There is a way to get only that field?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Basicfilters):

```
cat response | jq .range.total
```

Comment: I need to achieve it with REST, is it possible?

Comment: @maoryadin im afraid not